# UIView size different in editor and emulator

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode4

I have an UIView that takes up the entire screen and inside it I have another square UIView. I set this one to the size that I want but when I run the emulator I see it much smaller.

[image]

I'm using XCode 4. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the constraints you have, the top of the view is a certain distance from the top, and the bottom of the view is a certain distance from the bottom.  So it's not really a *square* view, it's just a view that looks like a square.

The reason why it's showing up as smaller is that it looks like a square when the view is run on a 4" screen.

But your simulator isn't a 4" screen (which you can clearly see because the height of the view in the simulator does not match the height of the view in Interface Builder).

So, since the simulator screen is shorter, it's forcing your view to be shorter too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what you say, but if I want the view to be "square" in any screen size what do I have to do?

Comment: @maxichiesa use different constraints; constrain the top of the view to the top of its superview (if that's what you want), but then give the view a fixed height; i.e., don't constrain the bottom of the view to the bottom of the superview.